# Backup an ATMEGA16

Tags: spi, isp, atmega16u2

I have an ATMEGA16 lying around that was in an old robot I'd bought. It was in a socket, so I pulled it out and was thinking of using this page to use it with Arduino IDE. Is there a way for me to backup the chip's current state, so as to be able to restore it if I mess up?
I don't have an SPI programmer with me, but I do have a Arduino Uno available at hand

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107479/discussion-on-question-by-fitz-watson-backup-an-atmega16).

Answer (score 1):

A [detailed how to is here](https://hardwarefun.com/tutorials/use-arduino-as-an-isp-programmer-to-program-non-arduino-avr-microcontrollers) its for the ATMega16 but check connections with the circuit diagram. 
[image: Flash ATMEGA16 with UNO]

Use this command for backup of flash

```
 avrdude -c avrisp2 -p m16 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -U flash:r:Old_flash_backup_file.hex:h
```

Backup EEPROM (just in case there is something stored there)

```
avrdude -c avrisp2 -p m16 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -U eeprom:r:eeprom_backup_file.hex:h
```

and this for writing the new bootloader / backup back

```
 avrdude -c avrisp2 -p m16 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:New_BootLoader.hex:i -v
```

and this for EEPROM writing back

```
avrdude -c avrisp2 -p m16 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -U eeprom:w:new_eeprom_file.hex:h
```

As your avr-dude outputis

```
lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
```

there seems to be no lock on the chip. As you are on LINUX when reading youhave tospecify the format :h hex when reading

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107476/discussion-on-answer-by-codebreaker007-backup-an-atmega16).